# What's the advantage of using an SLS system rather than a number of small lift rockets?

Tags: rockets, nasa, hllv, sls

I just read [this article](http://arstechnica.com/science/2013/09/nasas-original-flight-director-calls-agencys-direction-a-tragedy/), in which former director Kraft is described as deriding NASA's current plan to use a single heavy-lift vehicle (Space Launch System, or SLS) as a primary launch platform. Why is NASA doing this?

A single failure destroys an enormous amount of work. Distributing the across rockets increases the possibly of a single failure, but a single failure results in less loss. Furthermore, the smaller rockets exist today, so it doesn't require a huge new new development effort. Since they exist today, a lot of the design flaws have already been discovered and corrected.

Comment: An _excellent_ question!  I have had interactions with the planners for human Mars and asteroid missions, and they consider a large number of launches for a mission to be "unrealistic", and is one of their primary metrics for evaluating an architecture (the other being total IMLEO, initial mass in low Earth orbit).  I never got a good rationale for why fewer launches is better.

Comment: I'm with you that you reduce your exposure to launch failures when you have more of them.  Furthermore, the more you fly, the more reliable they get.  So it is not necessarily true that you increase the probability of a single failure.  You can have too _few_ launches of a given design for it to be reliable enough.

Comment: Au contrair, an entire Mars mission consisting of 4 Atlas Heavy to dock in LEO, instead of 1 SLS, is scrapped if 1 of the launches fails. Already launched components may have to be deorbited, cryo fuel tanks in LEO boil off and the launch window is lost for 2 years. However, Atlas and Ariane have 97% success rate and its getting better, we're not in the wild 1960s anymore. And I know of none, out of 100+ dockings in LEO or Lunar orbit which has failed catastrophically. I recommend "The Space Show" archive where exactly your question is debated so often that the host is sick and tired of it.

Comment: "Au contrair, an entire Mars mission consisting of 4 Atlas Heavy to dock in LEO, instead of 1 SLS, is scrapped if 1 of the launches fails. Already launched components may have to be deorbited, cryo fuel tanks in LEO boil off and the launch window is lost for 2 years." Unlike SLS, Atlas Vs can launch frequently. There've already been 3 launches in 2014. If one Atlas V fails, a new one can be launched before cyro boils off.

Comment: @HopDavid, that's assuming that you have a backup copy of the payload ready to be launched. Which isn't necessarily a bad thing, and could even be a good thing. If you build one backup copy of each component being launched, you could then use those backups for the next two year window (and build new backups that would then be used later, and so on). But still, building a backup copy of each component is expensive, which is something mission planners look at heavily.

Comment: One mission plan that avoid a lot of those issues is to launch the non perishable components (into orbits like the ISS) months ahead of time with nice widely spaced launch windows and do the dockings and checkout on an un-rushed schedule. The only time critical component becomes the last docking with the cryo-fuel. If anything goes wrong, you can let the rest of the mission sit in orbit for 2 years without any harm.

Comment: @Nickolai most of the mass delivered would be propellent. Dirt cheap compared to the dry mass hardware and not that hard to replace.

Comment: @BCS *"you can let the rest of the mission sit in orbit for 2 years without any harm"* **Assuming,** of course, that the hardware is designed to survive an additional two years in at least LEO. Which means you'll need to maintain the orbit (costs fuel, at the very least), you'll likely need additional radiation hardening (which at least costs weight = fuel = more weight = more fuel = ..., and likely costs noticable amounts of cash), and possibly other things I'm not thinking of right now.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That all depends on the mission. If you put your parking orbit up around 500+ miles (i.e. above Hubble) then fuel won't be much of an issue for that timeline. If it's going to Mars, sitting in LEO will likely be the lowest rad environment it needs to survive in and it will almost certainly have a >>2 year lifetime.

Answer (score 4):

Just guesses but:

- Avoiding rendezvous in orbit and the extra equipment that takes?
- Amortizing the lift cost of things that scale sub-linearly?

Also, at first blush, it doesn't sound like they are thinking of putting multiple major payloads on a single super-sized booster.

Comment: Do you think they're talking about a single 120-ton component, then?

Comment: @DonBranson Given that the N1 has a payload of 100T to LEO and the Saturn V can do 130T, I'd think that would be not unreasonable. Given such a booster, I'd consider things like a 15m space telescope or a multi-rover mars mission. --- OTOH, if you want that class of booster why not just update the S-V designs a bit?

Comment: NASA would also be biased toward big, distinctive projects in part because of the political nature of its funding (being spectacular feeds national pride--politicians winning votes by saying "I supported apple pie^W^Wthat magnificent space mission"--and spending money in more states--"I brought jobs to our fair state"), especially with commercial launch services becoming increasingly more capable in lower investment and more cost-effective areas.

Comment: In addition, it simplifies construction, reduces the origami type spacecraft issues, connectors, etc.

Comment: Re: commercial launch services -> "I support the Capitalist way!"

Comment: "Amortizing the lift cost of things that scale sub-linearly?" No sure what you mean. Surface to volume ratio grows with size. This an economy of larger rockets

Comment: But there is another amortization that favors small rockets. Flight rate. With a high flight rate design and development costs can be amortized over many units. When the flight rate is once a year (as with the SLS), it is likely each rocket will bear a large fraction of the development costs.

Comment: @HopDavid, extreme examples of <O(n) costs: The guidance computer likely costs the same for most any rocket. A more relevant example: launch facility support service costs likely have many fixed-cost-per-launch line items.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there are plenty of launch system available in the world for the 10t - 20t range, but none which can get more than 23 tons to low earth orbit. The SLS, however, will have a LEO capacity of 70t - 130t. That would open up a whole new market segment on which neither ESA nor Roskosmos can offer anything.

There is, however, another player who emerges on the market for launch systems and who is currently developing a rocket with LEO capacity in that scale: China with its Long March 9. Leaving that market exclusively to the Chinese could be a dangerous move from a geopolitical point of view. The Chinese having a world-wide monopoly on launching 100t chunks into orbit would be quite a problem for US international interests.

Comment: What market? Using an HLV to deliver sats is like using a Mack truck to deliver pizza. Same goes for delivering supplies to the I.S.S. If we wanted to send humans beyond LEO, there are alternatives to HLV. For example http://www.ulalaunch.com/site/docs/publications/AffordableExplorationArchitecture2009.pdf

Answer (score 0):

From the article:

> It's been derisively referred to as the "Senate Launch System" in a lot of places, because it's being designed and built in a very distributed manner, with work being spread across many different contractors in many different states.

That says it for me. The SLS is a make work program that provides employment in areas the senators represent. Also known as pork.

Comment: That's necessarily the way governments do things. So I think it is an irrelevant criticism, it is just stating the bleeding obvious. It's either SLS, another as inefficient governmental small rocket program, or no governmental rocket program. Personally, I'm looking forward to the huge SLS. Private sector or the much smaller foreign space agencies would never develop such a heavy lift so it's NASA or noone. Once it exists there'll be political pressure to make up missions for it, and that'll be exciting.

Comment: * Private sector or the much smaller foreign space agencies would never develop such a heavy lift so it's NASA or noone."

Correct, NASA or noone. A competitive market needs several providers. A single provider monopoly has less incentive to keep costs down. In fact if it's a cost plus contract, they have incentive to boost costs.

"Once it exists..."

There's no guarantee it will exist. The Ares rockets  did not come to pass.

"there'll be political pressure to make up missions " 

So far political pressure hasn't provided the needed funding.

Comment: Maybe the military wants the SLS for some secret monster mission. And when the US military wants something, costs are completely ignored as a parameter in decision making. I mean, they do rule the government, no one else has a say about what the military does or doesn't. And to make it look better NASA might be allowed to use it once or twice for science or human missions.

Comment: "Maybe the military wants the SLS for some secret monster mission" Unfounded speculation. Besides the military has it's own aerospace program http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Force_Space_Command

Comment: Yes, it's bleedingly obvious that our elected reps look after their constituents. But when they do so at the expense of the greater good, that's pork. Right now Senator Shelby et al are trying to protect the status quo from upstarts like SpaceX or Blue Origin. Much like Senator Owen Brewster tried to protect his supporters from that upstart Howard Hughes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen_Brewster#Opposition_to_Howard_Hughes